# NVD3.JS Angular Directives - Display date

Tags: angularjs, date, nvd3.js

I'm using Nvd3 angular directives (http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/) and more particularly the sparklines (http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/sparkline.chart.html)

I'd like to display the date as day & month, rather than as a timestamp.

Do I have to go modify the directive itself or is there a way to change the display directly ?

In the function, if I try to change d[0] as new Date(d[0]), no date is displayed since I guess the directive cannot sort the date any more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be undocumented, but you can do:

```
    var timeFormat = '%b %e %H:%M';
    $scope.xtickformat = function() {
        return function(d) {
            return d3.time.format.utc(timeFormat)(new Date(d));
        }
    }
```

And then, in your sparkline directive:

```
xtickformat = "xtickformat()"
```